# Save an e-mail drafted in the MFMailConfigureViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, email

My app uses the MFMailConfigureViewController.

Consider the following scenario.

1. My user was previously working on this screen
2. Now, he chooses to go to background or kill the app.
3. I need to show MFMailConfigureViewController controller on view whenever my app enters the foreground the next time with the changes made at the previous time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserDefaults to store the data that he types the previous time. When he reopens, show the MFMailConfigureViewController. Then present the NSUserDefaults data on the screen.

Hope this helps you to start..

Good Tutorial to start: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

EDIT:

You can derive the class from MFMailComposerViewController. Override the setMessageBody method. When user calls this method, store body into class variable(declared in your derived class). Use it when delegate method gets called.

Comment: Since the MFMailConfigureViewController API does not support any getter, how can I extract the details to save?

Comment: and what happens when the user edits it? I have a problem retrieving the changes, and not while the initial text is being set

Comment: The comment in the api about the setMessagebody: isHTML: method says
<br><br>
`/*
 @discussion This method will set the body of the email message.
 **This should be called prior to display.**
 The user's signature, if specified, will be added after the body content.
 <br>@param      body A NSString containing the body contents of the email message.
 <br>@param      isHTML  A boolean value indicating if the body argument is to be interpreted as HTML content.
 */
- (void)setMessageBody:(NSString *)body isHTML:(BOOL)isHTML;`